# My backup HDD comes formatted with exFAT; should I reformat it?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, filesystems, exfat

I've gotten an HDD for backup purposes. I intend to backup various kinds of files from my desktop computer - nothing special to make assumptions about. Now, the HDD has been preformatted with an exFAT file system.

My question: Is it advisable to switch to another filesystem (i.e. reformat it), e.g. with ext4 or btrfs? Or is exFAT "good enough"?

Comment: Linux of windows?

Comment: @Moab: I'm on Linux, but it doesn't matter all that much - I'm backing up files and directories, not filesystems.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your OS, but if you have multiple computers you backing up, then use exFat. Its supported by basically most OSes, ext4 doesnt work on windows, and ntfs doesn’t work on linux or MacOS natively. Fat32 is very old and has some problems. Ya, i would say exFAT is good enough because of the support and usability balance.

Answer (score 0):

I would make multiple primary partitions (as opposed to logical/extended), of different sizes, and with different filesystems.

For example:

- First partition with 5% of the disk size, in FAT32
- Second partition with 95% in ex-FAT

The rationale behind this is: ex-FAT is apparently more wildly supported than NTFS, and also has more features; and FAT32 is just perfectly compatible with just about anything. So should you have a problem with a system that needs backup now, and can only mount FAT32, you still would have a partition to write to; but for most of the space, you would have a modern filesystem.

That is, of course, assuming all the operating systems you would mainly use support both ex-FAT and multiple partitions on an external drive.

Comment: I don't need to perform backup from old/esoteric systems... edited my question to clarify this.

Comment: Then provided all the Operating Systems you want to use support ex-FAT, I would keep that for the sake of simplicity.